# What is the direction and orientation of a pendulum's acceleration at the ends of the oscillation? And at the midpoint?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, vectors, velocity, speed

A simple pendulum (a body oscillating at the end of a wire) describes an arc of a circle at each oscillation.

What is the direction and orientation of the body's acceleration at the ends of the oscillation?

And at the midpoint?

Comment: Try a PhET simulation: https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/pendulum-lab

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know the equation of motion$^{\dagger}$ of a simple (small angle) pendulum, call it $\theta(t)$.

The *angular acceleration* $\alpha$ is given by:

$$\alpha=\frac{{\rm d}^2\theta}{{\rm d}t^2}$$

Let the period of oscillation be $T$, then the first 'end' of the oscillation is reached at $t=T/4$, plugging this in the equation of motion will then give you $\alpha(T/4)$.

And the midpoint is for $t=0$, so you get: $\alpha(0)$.

The *tangential accelerations* $a$ are given by $a=\alpha l$.

$^{\dagger}$ Hint: the [Newtonian equation of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion#Mass_of_a_simple_pendulum) is:

$$-mgl\theta=I\frac{{\rm d}^2\theta}{{\rm d}t^2}$$

Comment: What does the question mean by distinguishing between "direction" and "orientation"?  One implies the other surely?  This sounds like a badly framed question. There are lot of bad courses out there. This sounds like one.

Comment: @mikestone It isn't very well framed, agreed.